# Can we execute code through textfields in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

```
var hello = "sad"
var u = "\(hello)"
println(u) // it prints sad

@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   println(myTextField.text)
}
```

To the text field i pass "\(hello)", but i don't see the value in the log.

Comment: Did you set delegate for the text field to self?

Comment: It will print "\\(hello)" in the log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

short answer, no.

long answer, the (hello) is evaluated at compile time, and hence wont work at run time through a text field.

Answer (score 3):

No, this will of course not work. And it would be a serious security issue if it would.

At compile time the compiler detects those `\()` and compiles these strings to use string interpolation in the assembly/machine code. You can think of this as if the `compiler` would turn `"Hello \(name)"` into `"Hello " + name`.

At runtime these strings are just collections of characters for whose content nobody cares.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is accept javascript code and execute it in UIWebView.

Yes, it is useless, provides you with no value other than fun and it is totally insane. That is why I am proposing it in the first place :)